# ¿Como puedo agregar elementos a un documento .XML?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Nesecito agregar nodos o elementos a un archivo .XML guardado en una ubicacion de mi PC y no se como hacerlo ...

por ejemplo en mi archivo tengo:

```
<Empleado> 
  <Nombre>
     <PrimerNombre>Efrain</PrimerNombre>
     <SegundoNombre>Emilio</SegundoNombre>
  </Nombre>
</Empleado>
```

y nesecito agregarle

```
<Apellido>
     <PrimerApellido>Mejias</PrimerApellido>
     <SegundoApellido>Castillo</SegundoApellido>
</Apellido>
```

para que quede asi :

```
<Empleado> 
  <Nombre>
     <PrimerNombre>Efrain</PrimerNombre>
     <SegundoNombre>Emilio</SegundoNombre>
  </Nombre>
  <Apellido>
     <PrimerApellido>Mejias</PrimerApellido>
     <SegundoApellido>Castillo</SegundoApellido>
  </Apellido>
</Empleado>
```

¿Como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: [Te podría interesar esto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb387089(v=vs.120).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
        XElement root = new XElement("Apellido");
        root.Add(new XElement("PrimerApellido", "Mejias"));
        root.Add(new XElement("SegundoApellido", "Castillo"));

        doc.Element("Empleado").Add(root);
        doc.Save("XMLFile2.xml");
```